# You don't have permission to access / on this server. Centos

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I have a Centos server, and I'm trying to configure php and apache, but I just can't get anything to work.

I'm have the next relevant info on my httpd.conf:

```
Listen 8088
Listen 8089

ServerName 192.168.124.243:8088

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

NameVirtualHost *:8089

<VirtualHost *:8089>
ServerAdmin webmaster@bitacora.com
DocumentRoot /root/bitacora/public
ServerName bitacora.com
ServerAlias www.bitacora.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorLog /root/bitacora/log/bitacora-error_log
CustomLog /root/bitacora/log/bitacora-access_log common
    <Directory "/root/bitacora/public">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Require All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My /var/www/html folder is empty, I only have remote access to the server, and I'm modifying configuration files through ssh and adding files through ftp.

When I type http://192.168.124.243:8088/ I get the default apache page, since I have nothing inside my html folder.

But if I try to access my virtualhost through http://192.168.124.243:8089/ I get the You don't have permission to access / on this server error and I get the Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/
error on my log file.

I read many post about this error and they mostly suggest adding Indexes to the /var/wwww/html directory, but it is there, and I have added the ports to the firewall exception, I've been trying to configure this thing for hours without success.

I have tried many many things, mainly many differents attempts on the httpd.conf file, but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
So it seems that the Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/ has no relation, I added an empty index.html to the /var/www/html folder and the error is gone, BUT I still get the You don't have permission to access / on this server error.

Comment: Have you tried to change your folder's permissions?
https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=45213

Comment: I did chmod 755 /root/bitacora, as suggested by the guide I was reading, but it didn't work.